# JQuery draggable update array after delete

Tags: jquery, arrays, droppable

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, I am certain that my JQuery is "clumsy" to say the least but it gets the first part of the job done.

I am dragging "products" to a basket like this:

```
$j('#basket').droppable({ 
accept: '.productsimg',
drop: function(ev, ui) { 
        $j(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
        $j("#basket .deleteit").show();
        $j('#basket .instructions').hide();
        $j("#basket .quantityIndicator").show();
        $j("#basket").css("background-image","none");
        $j('#basket .productsimg').removeClass('productsimg');
        $j('#basket .attachment-100x100').css('width','50px');
        $j('#basket .attachment-100x100').css('height','50px');
        $j("#basket .hiddentitle").show();  
        var result = $j('#basket').sortable('toArray');

        alert(result);
        $j('#total').load('/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/shop/test.php');
      } 
});
```

Yes I am also "manipulating the CSS" after dropping.  So far the only way I can "get" the dropped elements ID is to set basket as a sortable like this

```
$j('#basket').sortable({ 

});
```

By doing that I can use the "result" alert to see the arrayed ID's - that works, but I am sure it's not right.  What doesn't work is when I remove a dropped item from the basket like this:

```
$j("#basket .deleteit").live('click',function(){
    $j(this).parent().remove();
    var test = $j('#basket').sortable('toArray');
    alert(test);
    var num = $j('#basket .deleteit').length
    if (num == 0) {
       $j('#basket .instructions').show();
       $j("#basket").css("background-image","url(/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/shop/img/cart.png)");
    }
});
```

What I actually want to happen is the basket array to update.  But it doesn't. Any clues please.  Thanks. - Oh and please try and keep it "simple" as I am "very simple" at JQuery

Comment: do `$j(this).parent().remove();` at the end of the live click execution...

Comment: Thanks Reigel, but unless I am missing something the $j(this).parent().remove(); is at the end of the live click execution - no?

Comment: @russp - yours is `$j("#basket .deleteit").live('click',function(){ $j(this).parent().remove(); ....some codes..... });` Have you tried, `$j("#basket .deleteit").live('click',function(){ .... ...some codes... .... $j(this).parent().remove(); });` ?

Comment: @Reigel - Thanks again, yes tried "both" but thinking about it is there a JQ function that can be used "after" the delete and before the alert (some code) . i.e. click function -> delete ->if delete then this?

Comment: @Reigel Oh - b4 forget, comments are GR8 but I cannot accept an answer, just thinking of your rep. thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, is something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gLRnW/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yours is

```
$j("#basket .deleteit").live('click',function(){ 
     $j(this).parent().remove(); 
     //....some codes..... 
 });
```

Have you tried,

```
$j("#basket .deleteit").live('click',function(){ 
    //.... ...some codes... .... 
    $j(this).parent().remove(); 
});
```

**edit:** based on your post's comment

```
var result = $("ul#someId li").map(function(){
   return this.id;
}).get();
// result is now an array containing the id's of li.
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gLRnW/)

Comment: @Reigel - oops  - sorry nothing seems to work may be I am NOT using an unordered list, would love to say you are right but I suspect it is my Jquery functions that are preventing the delete from altering the basket array, for me back to the drawing board and I'll propably just use click rather than drag & drop - shame but the D&D documentation is so poor/unclear that I guess (from what I have seen) lots of people will not/cannot get their heads round it.  D&D really needs a good tuturial - not just the many "copied" ones that don't actually work.  Thanks again 4 all your help.

Comment: will `.map()` and `.get()` works on all kinds of dom element... as long as it's a collection... hmmm may i know your `#basket` structure...

Comment: @Reigel Sorry missed this comment - "will .map() and .get() works", just found it will "simplyfy" #basket for you has images etc and some hidden div's that show when dropped

Comment: @Reigel - This is the "bit that drags" - <div class="productsinner">
<div class="productsimg" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<div class="basketrow" >
<img src="/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/shop/img/no.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" width="16px" height="16px" border="0" class="deleteit" />
<?php the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100)); ?>
<div class="hiddentitle" > <?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="quantityIndicator"><div class="up"></div><div class="testit">1</div><div class="down"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: And the basket it this - <div class="clearfix" id="basket"><div class="instructions">Drag your purchases to here</div></div>

Comment: The JQuery is as originally posted

Comment: typo error on my part, "well", not "will", sorry for that... hmmm... I guess you can not use `.map()` and `.get()`... because the structure is changed... if it's just a simple sibling structure(like `li` s), it would be easy... but I guess it's not..

Comment: OK I can always change it :) to ul/li's

Comment: Oh btw I don't like the "design" so no comments please :)

Comment: @Reigel Thanks I have got it working by changing to ul/li's you have been "fantastic"